# Importing contacts and adding to a group also adds contacts with imported relationships to the same group

Tags: import, groups, relationships

I'm importing a CSV of contacts with a relationship to other contacts and adding the new contacts to a group. To my surprise, the group ended up with more contacts than I had imported. I saw that all the contacts who had their contact id in the relationship column were also added to the group.

Bug that should be reported? Strange, but expected behaviour?

Specifically, in this case, the relationship was employee of and the employer contacts were of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange behavior, but it's been the case for at least nine years and probably longer.  I think that until the import is overhauled (work that is slowly but surely happening) we shouldn't change behavior out from under folks.

Comment: Thanks, make sense.